# Using drawRect with QQuickPaintedItem::paint()

Tags: qt, qml

I write a sample code:

```
class Element : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    void paint(QPainter *painter)
    {   
        painter->setBrush(Qt::blue);
        painter->drawRect(contentsBoundingRect());
    }
}
```

and the qml:

```
Element {       
    x : 19
    y : 37
    width : 371
    height : 201
}
```

the left edge and top edge are fine, but the right edge and bottom edge are disappear!

Do I make some mistakes?

ps: I use QT5.3 in WIN XP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The bottom and right edge are drawn outside of the bounding rect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/coordsys.html#aliased-painting).

Here you can see how the rect is drawn when using the following code:

```
QPainter painter(this);

painter.setPen(Qt::darkGreen);
painter.drawRect(1, 2, 6, 4);
```

[image]

You can try drawing an [antialiased rectangle](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/coordsys.html#anti-aliased-painting), though it might look weird and cut off at the right and bottom edges, or you can just subtract 1 from the bottom and the right edge.